# couchdb file to json

Tags: json, database, couchdb

I have a CouchDB file and I'd like to convert it to json data.

So far everything I found on the internet has been about dumping the server database into a json file.

I tried to put the file in CouchDB\var\lib\couchdb after installing the server, but I couldn't find a guide on how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to load a .couch file you need to make sure you are loading it into the same version of CouchDB that your .couch file was created with. I'm not sure how to determine that based on the .couch file, but perhaps you can figure it out based on the source of the .couch file. Then you need to copy it to /var/lib/couchdb and make sure it has the same owner and permissions as any other .couch files in there. Probably just doing

```
chown couchdb:couchdb *.couch
```

will be enough. Then restart couchdb, probably by doing:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb restart
```

And you should have it loaded into your couchdb instance. At this point you can then use one of the dump to json approaches that you have mentioned.